# set value for jqxDropDownlist when ajax success

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, jqwidget

i hava jqxDropDownlist like this

```
var source = {
    datatype: “json”,
    datafields: [{ name: 'title'}, { name: 'id'}],
    id: ‘id’,
    url: “getOnvaneOrganizations”,
    async: true
};
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
$(“#slc_onvane_organization_sabt”).jqxDropDownList({
    selectedIndex: 0,
    source: dataAdapter,
    displayMember: “title”,
    valueMember: “id”,
    theme: ‘darkblue’,
    filterable:true,
    width:’100%’,
    rtl:true
});
$(“#slc_onvane_organization_sabt”).jqxDropDownList(‘val’,’10′);
```

because async is true so then `$("#slc_onvane_organization_sabt").jqxDropDownList('val','10');` runs before ajax success, and not worked.

how can run `$("#slc_onvane_organization_sabt").jqxDropDownList('val','10');` in ajax.success function?

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> jqxDataAdapter: downloadComplete(edata, textStatus, jqXHR): A callback
>   function which is called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter; a string describing
>   [jqxDataAdapter](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxdataadapter/jquery-data-adapter.htm)

and for other element like jqxdropdownlist have `bindingComplete`

> This event is triggered when the data binding operation is completed.
>   Code example
>
> Bind to the bindingComplete event by type: jqxDropDownList.
>
> $("#jqxDropDownList").on('bindingComplete', function (event) { });
>
> Try it: [Bind to the bindingComplete event by type:jqxDropDownList](http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/FGGMU/)

so then with this code can change value of jqxDropDownList when `bindingComplete`

```
$("#slc_onvane_organization_sabt").on('bindingComplete', function (event) { 
        $("#slc_onvane_organization_sabt").jqxDropDownList('val','10');
 });
```